# Creación de tablas

Tags: mysql

soy nuevo en esto de MySQL, (prometo leer mucho y aprender con los tutoriales).

Quisiera que me ayudarán a crear una tabla donde me muestre las ventas desglosadas por mes, y en distintos años de todos los clientes que tengo.

Ejemplo:

Cliente : José Ramos
Venta : 1500
Fecha : Enero 2017

Espero me puedan ayudar, y de antemano les agradezco mucho.
Ojalá me allá entendido.

Comment: Tendrías que introducir algo de código que hayas intentado... Y a poder ser, replantea algo mejor la pregunta, no esta muy clara.

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento, ya realizaste alguna investigación previa a la pregunta. De paso te dejo los siguientes enlaces, para que mejores tu pregunta.
[¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878)

Comment: Más que crear una tabla es la creación de una consulta que retorne eso